# vector of ofstream pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, error-handling, ofstream

Here is my problem, I need to create X number of files and write to them depending on different factos, my solution was to create a vector of ofstream pointers like this

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
vector<ofstream*> files;
files.resize(SplitVec.size()-4);
          for(i=0;i<SplitVec.size()-4;i++)
          {
              line="/Users/jorge/Desktop/testing/strain_"+lexical_cast<string>(i);
              cout<<"ine"<<endl;
              files[i]=new ofstream(line.c_str());
          }
```

Until this part it creates the files great, and later in the program I write to them, which is also great, my problem is when I want to close the objects, if I use:

```
for(i=0;i<SplitVec.size()-4;i++)
          {
              *files[i].close();
          }
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:14:./methyl.h:298: error: request for member 'close' in 'files. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::ofstream*, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::ofstream*>](1ul)', which is of non-class type 'std::ofstream*'
```

So, I have a question, first, why cant I call close, its a pointer to an ofstream, so with *files[i], I would have imagined I could close it, second, if I don't close it, the program works ok, but im almost sure that this is a bad practice and don't want to be a lazy or crappy programer, Ive looked as much as I could, but Ive failed finding an answer.
Thank you!!!

Comment: if you see the chance, use a `vector<std::unique_ptr<ostream> >` to avoid resource leaks. (or `boost::scoped_ptr`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not exception safe (e.g. if an exception is thrown, since you have a vector of *raw* pointers, they are **leaked** - with the associated stream handles).

I'd suggest a *modern C++* RAII approach.

For example, if you use a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` (from Boost, or from C++11 `<memory>` header), you could build a `vector` of `shared_ptr`'s, and use `make_shared` to allocate the `ofstream` objects:

```
// RAII exception-safe approach
vector<shared_ptr<ofstream>> files;

// Add a new ofstream object to the vector:
files.push_back( make_shared<ofstream>( filename ) );
```

When the vector goes out of scope, it's destructed, and all the pointed stream objects are *automatically* released: very simple, clear, and exception-safe.

If you want to force streams cleanup before vector goes out of scope, you can just call `.clear()` method on the vector.

(An alternative could be to use C++11 *move-semantics*-powered `unique_ptr`, and define a `vector<unique_ptr<ofstream>>`, but unfortunately there is no standard equivalent of `make_shared` for `unique_ptr`, and the code could be a bit more verbose, unless you write a custom implementation of `make_unique`, like [the one proposed by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/).)

Note that the usual `files[i]->close()` syntax applies also in this case of vector of *smart* pointers.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
(*files[i]).close();
```

or directly

```
files[i]->close();
```

Comment: that was surprisingly simple, may I ask why *files[i] alone doesnt work?

Comment: @JorgeKageyama because of precedence. It's parsed as `*(files[i].close())`.